# ubuntu set up as router lan pc can ping one direction and get shares but other direction can not ping or connect shares

Tags: ubuntu, router, ping, local-area-network, shares

I have ubuntu router questions.
you can see tracert can complete on way but not other way.
How to make that work?

(a better visual layout exists here)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12444760#post12444760

This way from second win7 works to first win7

```
C:\Users\scott>tracert 192.168.200.36

Tracing route to WIN7 [192.168.200.36]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  SCOTT-P5QC [10.42.0.1]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  wr850g.hr.cox.net [192.168.1.1]
  3    25 ms    24 ms    31 ms  WIN7 [192.168.1.100]
  4    18 ms    17 ms    40 ms  WIN7 [192.168.200.36]
```

Trace complete.

C:\Users\scott>

This way from first win7 to second win7 broken

```
C:\Users\scott>tracert 10.42.0.19

Tracing route to 10.42.0.19 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    52 ms     1 ms     1 ms  hubrouter.westell.com [192.168.200.1]
  2    43 ms    98 ms    45 ms  192.168.1.1
  3    45 ms   105 ms    24 ms  SCOTT-PC [192.168.1.102]
  4  SCOTT-PC [192.168.1.102]  reports: Destination protocol unreachable.</pre>
```

Trace complete.

From first win7 to ubuntu router works

```
C:\Users\scott>tracert 10.42.0.1

Tracing route to SCOTT-P5QC [10.42.0.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1   105 ms    <1 ms     4 ms  hubrouter.westell.com [192.168.200.1]
  2    19 ms    17 ms    33 ms  192.168.1.1
  3    35 ms    34 ms     5 ms  SCOTT-P5QC [10.42.0.1]</pre>
```

Trace complete.

C:\Users\scott>

```
netstat routes in ubuntu router


scott@scott-P5QC:~$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         wr850g.hr.cox.n 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth2
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ </pre>
```

hand copy of lan layout

[image: Images]

Answer (score 0):

solved by installing webmin. Then used it to reset iptables.
Seriously great tool for administering the firewall. 
Webmin told me 2 rules were in the iptables which it could not understand, so I save iprules to a file, did a reset and all 3 pc can share files.

a firewall is defacto running all the time with iptables, so those tables must be modified.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-server.html

scott@scott-P5QC:~$ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.580_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package webmin.
(Reading database ... 229686 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking webmin (from webmin_1.580_all.deb) ...
Setting up webmin (1.580) ...
Webmin install complete. You can now login to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
as root with your root password, or as any user who can use sudo
to run commands as root.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
scott@scott-P5QC:~$

shows what it looks like
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/oX1xo7I07W38s4C7Laftv9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink